# angularjs single form for array of objects

Tags: angularjs

I am having below data in a controller -

```
$scope.template1 = {
    name: 'template1',
    blocks: [
        { id: 1, display: true, title: 'News' },
        { id: 2, display: true, title: 'News' },
        { id: 3, display: true, title: 'News' },
        { id: 4, display: true, title: 'News' },
        { id: 5, display: true, title: 'News' }
    ]
};
```

The blocks data is used to create informational blocks by using `ng-repeat` and on click of it i want to display form to edit its details.

One way is to do an `ng-repeat` and create separate forms for each block. But instead of that, I would like to have a common form for this and also when user is changing its data the changes needs to be reflected as a live preview. I have tried to have these forms generated dynamically but the binding doesn't work :(

Can any one please help on this or provide an example?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle to show your changes?

Comment: here it is - http://jsfiddle.net/Loyxxcnn/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the reference of the selected block in a scope variable and bind this to the input element.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="TestController" style="padding:10px;">
    <div ng-repeat="block in template1.blocks" class="blocks" ng-click="vm.selectedBlock = block">
        <span>{{block.title}}</span>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both" data-ng-show="vm.selectedBlock">
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.selectedBlock.title" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
function TestController($scope) {
    $scope.template1 = {
        name: 'template1',
        blocks: [
            { id: 1, display: true, title: 'News' },
            { id: 2, display: true, title: 'News' },
            { id: 3, display: true, title: 'News' },
            { id: 4, display: true, title: 'News' },
            { id: 5, display: true, title: 'News' }
        ]
    };

    $scope.vm = {}
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Loyxxcnn/3/)

Comment: Many thanks :), this is what i was looking for.. also do we have something like generating the input on the fly when we click on the block?

Comment: replace `data-ng-show` with `data-ng-if` to render the input only on selection of a block

Comment: sorry my bad.. my other question is that i don't wanna use the vm.selectedBlock. Lets say i have hundreds of different types of $scope entries and i want to generalize it so that on click of any type of element (lets say a span tag) on which the angular binding is, we generate an ng-model to modify it at runtime.. is this possible?

Comment: I don't think that is possible without using something like vm.selectedBlock